# AJAX and 404 equivlant

Tags: django, http, web

If I had a link that I expected to only received AJAX requests but was sent a synchronous request, I would just send back a 404.  Let's say that I have a link that I expect to only receive synchronous requests. What is the standard practice for handling the case where a user sends an AJAX request to that link?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a 405 Method Not Allowed, because AJAX isn't allowed at that synchronous address, or a 406 Not Acceptable because the request expects (I assume) JSON or XML, and you're returning HTML (again I assume).  I'm not aware of an industry standard here, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Sounds good. For some reason, it never clicked with me that there was a request/response header for AJAX requests. But it makes perfect sense that I would return a HTTP status code like one of the ones above. I will probably go with 405 after looking at the HTTP spec.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the existence of the Ajax header in user request: 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'